# What's the language of the NFA?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Given is the NFA `N`:

[image]

What's the language of this NFA? What's its complement?

---

I'm learning for a test and I'd like to know if I solved this task correctly.

The language `L` of the `NFA N` should look like this:

```
L(N) = {x ∈ Σ* | x mustn't include 'aba' and x mustn't end with 'ab'}
```

I have tried several different words and I couldn't find any word that breaks my language `L(N)`.

Assuming this is correct, how would the complement of `L(N)` look like?

It needs to be the opposite, right? So something like that (`~` stands for complement):

```
~L(N) = {x ∈ Σ* | x must include 'aba' and x must end with 'ab'}
```

Comment: You didn't use De Morgan's law correctly.

Comment: @Raphael Oh, then I need to replace the "and" with an "or" in ~L(N) ?

Comment: Try transforming it to a regular expression. This should give you immediately the language of the NFA.

Comment: @cnmesr ~(a&b) == ~a | ~b and ~(a|b) == ~a & ~b

Comment: Yes, your $L(N)$ is correct. It is somewhat easier to see what happens if you transform the automaton in an equivalent deterministic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried expanding my comment to a proper answer. It was easier for me to write down the automata and the whole transformation process rather than using some software to generate it, thus I hope my handwriting is legible enough ;) (elsewise let me know)

[image: NFA to REG]

The resulting **Regular Expression** is $[[b^*ba^*b]^*\cup[b^*aa^*ab^*b]^*]^*$

So the language accepted by your NFA ought to be something of the form $L = \{((b^lba^hb)^*(b^iba^jab^kb)^*)^*|i,j,k,l,h\ge 0\}^*$ (I've given a quasi-final form of the language).

The opposite of this language is $\sim L = \mathtt{REG} - L$

PS: Fortunately, a kind sir named [Hendrik Jan](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4287/hendrik-jan) observed that my conversion omits the fact that 2 is also a starting point. The solution is **still holds for starting point 1**. Now that you got an idea about NFA to REG conversions, I'll leave the REG determined by **starting point 2** to you. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for writing all that on an extra sheet of paper and posting it here! :) We just had regular expression in our reading today and this will help me a lot when I go through it (tomorrow because I need to sleep now). Maybe you can quickly tell me if my L(N) is correct, too?

Comment: Note the original automaton is *very* undeterministic in that it has two initial states.

Comment: Also, I do not sponsor the notation $\{\dots (a^lba^hb)^* \dots \mid j,h\ge 0\}$ for two reasons. (1) the regular expression is within set brackets. By itself the star-thing is already a set/language. (2) If you fix $l,h$ and then perform the star operation (as the notation suggests) you cannot repeatedly choose different values for $l,h$ when iterating.

Comment: eurmph. Also, the loop on node 1 is a $b$ in the original. Sorry, but it was not my intention to sound grumpy.

Comment: @HendrikJan No problem. In fact, thank you for pointing out my missinterpretations. I have taken into account only the initial state 1.

Comment: @cnmesr It is correct.